# How to place withApollo HOC on _app or _document level in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-apollo

I’ve finally managed to get SSR in Next.js to work with @apollo/react-hooks, but currently I need to wrap each page with `withApollo`, e.g:

```
export default withApollo(IndexPage)
```

Full source: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-graphql-hooks-boilerplate/blob/master/pages/articleList.js

How can I lift the `withApollo` HOC to _app.js or _document.js?